# GAS UrlFetchApp URL behind Google Domain SSO

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I usually use `UrlFetchApp` like this

```
var url = 'my_url'
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

However I am now trying to access a domain that requires Google Workspace login 'sign in with Google' in order to access the UI.

My params payload is prepared with the URL specific user and password authentication, but this would only be successful once signing in with Google.

How can I access the URL programmatically? Is there a way of sending Google auth with the URL?

The GAS script is running as me, the same account I would use to access the URL.

**EDIT**

The following function was working when testing the URL before the webapp was moved to a server requiring Google sign in. It returns content to obtain a key to use with other requests. Don't let the auth style throw you off, this is unusual but works.

The issue is that now we have moved this web app to be behind a google sign in page, so the user must first sign in with Google, then sign into the app.

So somehow I need to auth through Google then auth to the app as below.

```
function return_something() {

    var url = 'my_url';

    var myPayload = {
    "method": "login",
    "params": {
        "user": "my_username",
        "password": "my_password"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "auth": null
    };

    var headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    };

    var params = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': headers,
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(myPayload)
    };

    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

    var myObj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
    Logger.log(myObj)
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that you will have to use OAuth2 authentication rather than a URL to do the authentication with username and password. Please add more details about what you want to access "behind Google Domain SSO"

Comment: @Rubén see updated question

Comment: What settings did you choose for the web app when you deployed it? @redditor

Comment: @ale13 its not a gas web app, its an independent app that happens to be installed on a server that requires google login to access, then the user can log in to the app.